# Reflection, properties and attributes - Studying ORM architecture

Tags: c#, orm, properties, custom-attributes

I'm just playing with attributes, which contains some info about a specific database field. I've already created the FieldAttribute class and it has default information, like name, type, etc.

My question is: is it possible to create a single method to retrieve this information and embbed into properties? I think I can communicate better with code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property,AllowMultiple=false,Inherited=true)]
public class FieldAttribute:Attribute
{
    protected string _FieldName;
    protected esriFieldType _FieldType;
    protected bool _NotNullable;
    protected bool _IsPrimary;
    protected bool _IsForeign;
    protected int _Index;

    public virtual string FieldName
    {
        get { return this._FieldName; }
        set { this._FieldName = value; }
    }

    public virtual esriFieldType FieldType
    {
        get { return this._FieldType; }
        set { this._FieldType = value; }
    }

    public virtual bool NotNullable
    {
        get { return this._NotNullable; }
        set { this._NotNullable = value; }
    }

    public virtual int Index
    {
        get { return this._Index; }
        set { this._Index = value; }
    }

    public FieldAttribute(string fieldName, esriFieldType fieldType,int position)
    {
        this.FieldName = fieldName;
        this.FieldType = fieldType;
        _IsPrimary = false;
        _IsForeign = false;
        Index = position;
    }
}

// my main abstract class
public abstract class ObjectWrapper:IObjectWrapper
{
    protected int _ObjectId;
    protected IObject _UnderlyingObject;

    public virtual IObject UnderlyingObject
    {
        get { return this._UnderlyingObject; }
    }

    public virtual int ObjectId
    {
        get { return this._ObjectId; }
    }

    public virtual void Store()
    {
        try
        {
            _UnderlyingObject.Store();
        }
        catch (COMException comEx)
        {
            // log com exception
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log
        }
    }

    // this method retrieves field information
    private FieldAttribute GetFieldAttribute(string propertyName)
    {
        FieldAttribute propertyAttribute = null;

        try
        {
            PropertyInfo propInfo = this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            object[] attributes = propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FieldAttribute), true);
            if (attributes.Length == 1)
                propertyAttribute = (FieldAttribute)attributes[0];
        }
        catch (AmbiguousMatchException ambEx)
        {
            // log
        }
        catch (ArgumentException argEx)
        {
            // log
        }

        return propertyAttribute;
    }
}

// my concrete class
public class Foo:ObjectWrapper
{        
    [Field("FOO_NAME",esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeString,1);
    public string FooName { get; set; }

    [Field("FOO_AGE",esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeInteger,2);
    public int FooAge { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do here is to build a generic GetMethod, that uses Field attributes values to fetch the data from the database/_underlyingObject and just "fill out" the getter and setter for me.E.G:

when i call Foo.FooName, the getter will check for the attributes, passing the getter name to the GetFieldAttribute method.

How can I accomplish this?

The idea is that when there is a small framework, this will become a simple "ESRI database provider" for data.

I'm really sorry that I cannot explain this properly.

Thanks for all the help.

G.

Comment: Feel this needs to be said:  I hope this is for your own curiosity and not to be used in a production system.

Comment: @qstarin: why should not be used in production? the idea is that bad? i'm not saying that this will be used in production right away, but all projects must start somewhere. thank you for your help.

Comment: It would be *far* more productive to learn and use an existing ORM solution than to develop your own.  If it's for your own learning, there's value.  If this is paid work, it seems negligent and irresponsible (that's a little strong, but not far off).  The idea of writing your own ORM is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're planning on instantiating your Foo-object through some Data Repository Retrieval method, this would require dynamic compilation to inject the necessary into your getter and setters.

I would instead recommend you to look at a pattern like this

```
var foo = DataRepository.GetObject<Foo>(some_id);
```

the method signature of GetObject would be

```
public static T GetObject<T>(object id) where T: new()
```

In the GetObject method you will reflect over the type finding all its Field-attributes and mapping them to a actual database call. This is very simple and common approach and can be achieved like this

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<PropertyInfo, FieldAttribute>> GetFieldAttributes<T>()
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        var attribute = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FieldAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();
        if (attribute != null)
        {
            yield return new Tuple<PropertyInfo, FieldAttribute>(prop, attribute);
        }
    }
}
```

Now with a list og attributes you can construct a sql-string like this

```
var columns = GetFieldAttributes<T>().Select(t => t.Item2.FieldName);
var sql = "SELECT "+ String.Join("," columns) +" FROM table WHERE id = "+ id;

var result = ... execute the query and return ie a datareader
```

With the result you can instantiate a Foo-instance, fill out its properties and return the instance

```
var instance = new T();

result.Read()
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

// get the columns returned from database
for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
{
    string fieldName = reader.GetName(i);
    object value = reader.GetValue(i);

    dictionary.Add(fieldName, value);
}

// bind the columns from database to the properties of our object
foreach (var c in columns)
{
    var attr = c.Item2;
    var value = dictionary[attr.FieldName];

    if (value is DBNull)
    {
        value = null;
    }

    typeof(T).InvokeMember(c.Item1.Name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance, null, instance, new[] { value });
}

// return the new object with all its values filled out
return instance
```